# Best approach to collect and serialize large collections

Tags: c#, collections, large-data

So I have a collection of objects; say Person objects which needs to be serialized to a CSV file.

To elaborate:
I get data from database in batches of 40k-50k rows which are added to the Person collection
This summates to a little over million records
I need to serialize this to a csv file.

Language C#

Can you please suggest on an efficient way to achieve this?

Edit: What have I tried. 
I am using Dapper to fetch these batches of 50k records

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("@RequestId", new Guid("1B139CAB-1D53-467D-A013-03A5DB410937"));

                IEnumerable<Person> resultSet = _dbConn.Query<Person>(sql: "FetchPersons", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Once I fetch these into a collection I do the following:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"outPutFile.csv"))
                    {
                        foreach (Person person in personColl)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(person.FirstName + "," + person.LastName + "," + person.Param1 + "," + person.Param2 + "," + person.Param3);
                        }
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
```

Is the above approach appropriate?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Just open an SqlReader, read records one by one and write them to the file immediatelly. Or try the `bcp` tool: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of difficult to really give a good answer to this without knowing some more details of your actual implementation, but I'd probably just do something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = ...;

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        writer.Write("\"");
        for (int v = 0; v < reader.FieldCount; v++)
        {
            if (v > 0)
                writer.Write("\",\"");

            writer.Write(reader[v]);
        }
        writer.Write("\"");

        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

You could also grab the headers from the reader, too, if need be. You might also want to add in some escaping.